# Pointwise mutual information correction for negative bias

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information, pointwise-mutual-information

I am studying the point wise mutual information and I have understood that it has some limitations in NPL like the bias towards negative values (it tends to assign high scores to low-frequency events). I have seen that there are many possible correction and the most used is the PMI^k.
I am wondering whether it could make sense to use as a corrected PMI the single contribution to the mutual information, i.e.
$$p(x,y)\log\left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}\right)$$
Does this correct for the negative bias?

Comment: [Pointwise mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information)  is a specific case of a loglikelihood ratio